# Set origin to vertex in Edit Mode?

Tags: modeling

I want to make the origin in *Edit Mode* at a vertex, but it keeps setting it to the last clicked-on face.

Now in *Edit Mode* the pivot is on the last clicked-on face.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I suspect you want the [*Pivot*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point) (the location of the transform widget, RGB arrows) to remain on the last selected vertex while both vertex select mode and face select mode are enabled. Is this correct? If so, could you explain why you want this? AFAIK it's not possible but perhaps we could come up with a suitable alternative if we knew the use-case. If this is not what you want, could you clarify?

Comment: More information is needed.

Answer (score 26):

In Edit mode, make sure you enable vertex selection.

[image]

Click the vertex to which you want to set the origin.

While still in *Edit Mode*, *Mesh > Snap > Cursor to Selected* 
If all you want to do is change the pivot point, set it to 3D cursor.

[image]

If you actually want to change the origin.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Object mode, then *Object > Transform > Origin to 3D Cursor*.

Since Blender 2.8 it's *Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*.

Comment: But i need it to be on the most recent VERTEX after A is pressed in edit mode

Comment: @AidanPallian Then first click the vertex you want to be the origin or pivot point, then change the origin or pivot point as per the instructions, then, in Edit mode, select all. If the 3D cursor is snapped to that vertex, it will remain there even when you select all, and if the pivot point is set to 3D cursor, it will follow the 3D cursor, no matter which vertices are selected.

Comment: Complicated. Why can't Blender just add a menu like "Set this as the origin" in the Vertex menu?

Answer (score 6):

If you enable the shipped add-on: '3D Viewport Pie Menus', <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> will bring up the *Origins* pie, which includes 'Origin to Selected' in Edit Mode.

(On my system, I've had to remap it to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, because of conflict with the OS.)

Answer (score 4):

A practical alternative is:

- Enter in edit mode (in this mode the **origin menu** in the tool
  shelf hides and you are no more able to use it, but don't worry...);
- Select the vertex (one or more vertexes or edges, or faces) you want to use as referring for the new origin position.
  If you select more of them modify the Pivot Point to **Median Point**
  so blender will automatically calculate the median point accordingly
  with your selection;
- Press space bar to show the **dynamic space bar menu**;
- In Search text box of space bar menu insert: **Set Origin to
  Selected**; Confirm with **Return** or **left click** on **Set Origin to
  Selected** menu item;

Notice: once done the first time, you will be able to access and apply the command in future just pressing space bar and Return, until you don't search for another command into space bar dynamic menu.

The screenshot:

[image: The screenshot of the main steps to accomplish the operation]

Fast and effective...
Enjoy...

PS.: I don't know if there is an item in the tool shelf for **Set Origin to Selected** though: if there is I can't figure out where it is... In fact I use the space bar dynamic menu

Hope in the future blender releases the origin menu doesn't hide in edit mode and hope developers will add some more good options like the above so can be found faster and visually.

Comment: I don't have that option ;-;    nevermind I found a script that does it https://ghigiblend.wordpress.com/2011/11/25/script-set-origin-to-selected-blender-2-6x/

Comment: @UanpisCardada, Notice that I'm not sure yet if the command I used is blender native or comes with any plugin. I just activate all plugins in blender just out of the box

Comment: This option comes fromt he plugin "3D View: Dynamic Context Menu"

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to change the pivot point for a group of vertices I would try selecting a point and use Shift+S and Cursor to selected. Then at the top center of the window there is a small button with a drop down menu that says, "transform pivot point". If you select the option for 3D Cursor then you can use it as a pivot point for a group of selected vertices within an object and still stay in edit mode.
Sorry, I don't know the fancy terms for everything yet. I'm just getting started with Blender and figured this out myself.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the vertex in *Edit mode*.
2. Press <kbd>N</kbd>. *Transform->Vertex*.
3. Under the vertex coordinates change display values from Local to
   Global.
4. Copy and paste vertex coordinates to *Transform->3D cursor-> Location*.
5. Put pivot to the 3D cursor coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, Timaroberts.

Answer (score 2):

If you come from missing these options in the fashion of the *Object Context Menu > Set Origin > ...* and want to have this available real simple and quick, enable the *Interface: Dynamic Context Menu* addon and then you can find *Origin to selected V/F/E* available in the search menu. Just select your vertex/edge/face in edit mode beforehand and voila, the object got its new origin.
[image]