# Setting mesh's origin in python (2.8)

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh, origin

If I create a cube, the origin is originally at the center of mass. I know how to move the origin to the center of one of its faces using the interface, but how can I do the same thing via Python?

Comment: This might help you: https://blenderartists.org/t/modifying-object-origin-with-python/507305

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bmesh script**

This can be done similarly by using `me.transform(T)` with a translation matrix T. I have used an edit mode bmesh as it is simple to set  the active face interactively before running script.

- Get the local coordinate of the face center.
- Subtract it from all coordinates, effectively making face center (0, 0, 0) or origin.
- Move the object globally to reflect the local transform of the origin.

Script and *Origin to Selected* 2.80 addon available here 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134460/15543

[image]
*Addon from link above, same result as script below*

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

f = bm.faces.active
if f:
    o = f.calc_center_median()
    bmesh.ops.translate(bm,
           verts = bm.verts,
           vec = -o,
           )
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
    me.update()           
    # move the object globally to reflect
    mw = ob.matrix_world
    t = mw @ o - mw @ Vector()
    mw.translation += t
```

Since `mw @ Vector()` is essentially `mw.translation` the last line could be

```
     mw.translation = mw @ o
```

Related:  [Set origin to bottom center of multiple objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/set-origin-to-bottom-center-of-multiple-objects)

Answer (score 0):

ORIGIN TO CURSOR in edit mode

```
obj = context.active_object
loc = context.scene.cursor.location
me = obj.data
mw = obj.matrix_world

#move verts "back" (in prevision of next operation)
local = mw.inverted() @ loc 
ml = Matrix.Translation(-local)
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)                                
bm.transform(ml)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)

#move origin and verts
t = loc - mw @ Vector()
mw.translation += t
```