# Why there's no tool to move origin point in edit mode?

Tags: origin

Why there's no straight tool to move the origin in edit mode? The tool is only available in Object mode, like that handy <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>  .

I'm just curious , there must be some good reasons for this. Can someone explain ? it's been a question for me for quite long. I think this tool shold be applicable for both edit and object mode.

Comment: maybe ask this on blender dev forums or paper cuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to drag an object's origin around in Edit mode, but, at least, with the shipped  '*3D Viewport Pie Menus*' > '*Origins Pie*' add-on activated,you have the options, in Edit mode, to snap the origin of a Mesh to the cursor, or to element selections.

It seems not fully implemented for Curves: it toggles me out of Edit mode if I call 'Origin to Selection', before doing the right thing,  and flat-out refuses, if I call 'Origin to Cursor'.

Comment: Speculating on the why is it so:  the global origin is origin of global space,  as the object origin is for object (or local) space (edit mode)e. Imagine pie menu to selection is akin to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140637/15543 which involves  shifting local and object translations to keep mesh _"in place"_

Comment: @batFINGER  Would this not be possible for curves, then, just invert the translation of the control points?

Comment: Can't see why not.