# How to set origin to selected vertex for 2D shapes (fast) ? (blender 2.8 +)

Tags: objects, vertices, 3d-cursor, origin

is there a way to **set the origin to selected vertex** **faster**? (for both shapes and objects)
there are a lot of steps to do it right now and it's frustrating.

I found a **similar topic** but it's old and **not working** with blender 2.8 2.9 and ... .
an addon similar to this topic would be great.
[Shortcut for setting origin to vertex](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134440/shortcut-for-setting-origin-to-vertex/134441#134441)

thanks for your time.

Comment: AFAIC the addon linked to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134460/15543 does exactly this (written for 2.8, tested on 2.91).

Comment: thanks but it's not working with 2D shapes origin.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193145/how-can-i-make-a-custom-gizmos-to-set-the-origin/193202#193202

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can activate the "3D Viewport Pie Menus" vanilla addon,
there is a checkbox to enable "Origin Pie Menu" in its preferences.
Once activated, you can select a vertex/edge/face in Edit mode and with the shortcut choose to move origin to selection.

[image]

For curve objects: when you are in Edit mode, select a vertex, then in the Search menu search for the *Origin to selection*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Move grease pencil origin to average of selection in edit mode.**

_Note have not converted to operator or added shortcut, have simply pasted scripts into text editor and run via "Run Script" (play button).

[image]

I'm assuming by 2D shape you are referring to a grease pencil object.  The equivalent of method shown in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134460/15543 using GP is

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy import context


ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world

gp = ob.data
active_layer = gp.layers.active
active_frame = active_layer.active_frame
selected_points = [
        p for layer in gp.layers
        for frame in layer.frames
        for stroke in frame.strokes
        for p in stroke.points
        if p.select
        ]
if selected_points:
    cl = sum([p.co for p in selected_points], Vector()) / len(selected_points)
    for layer in gp.layers:
        for frame in layer.frames:
            for stroke in frame.strokes:
                for p in stroke.points:
                    
                    p.co -= cl
                    
    ob.matrix_world.translation = mw @ cl
```

**Move grease pencil origin to 3D cursor loc in edit mode.**

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy import context


ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world

scene = context.scene
cl = mw.inverted() @ scene.cursor.location
gp = ob.data
active_layer = gp.layers.active
active_frame = active_layer.active_frame
for layer in gp.layers:
    for frame in layer.frames:
        for stroke in frame.strokes:
            for p in stroke.points:
                
                p.co -= cl
                
ob.matrix_world.translation = scene.cursor.location
```

Comment: thanks for your time,i mean 2D curves,(in 3dsMax we use word SHAPE).

Comment: i've edited the "top answer" to be more accurate answer.

Comment: I see you have removed your comment doesn't work for 2D shapes there too.  Please instead  **edit your own question** using blender terminology like "2D curve" and "Control point" not vertex.

Comment: ok,sorry for that,and thank you.