# How to copy objects and set their origins with Python console?

Tags: python, command-line, origin

I am trying to copy Cube and set different random origins to the copies.
I use the following code:

```
import bpy
import random

C = bpy.context
src_obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']


for i in range (0,5):
    new_obj = src_obj.copy()
    new_obj.data = src_obj.data.copy()
    new_obj.animation_data_clear()
    C.collection.objects.link(new_obj)
    new_origin = (0.0+random.randint(1, 9)/100,0.0+random.randint(1, 9)/100,0.0+random.randint(1, 9)/100)
    print(new_origin)
    C.scene.cursor.location = new_origin
    new_obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')
```

The objects are successfully copied, but their origins are always the same: they are equal to last generated coordinates. I added print to make sure that new_origin is always different, but the last value of new_origin is applied. What I am doing wrong? How to make the origins to be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason all of them use the same location is because you are leaving them all selected.

```
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')
```

will set the object origin to ORIGIN_CURSOR for **all** selected objects.

Add:

```
new_obj.select_set(False)
```

as the last line in your for loop.

Answer (score 2):

**API Methods.**

Using the method shown here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134460/15543

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from random import randint
from bpy import context

ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world 

def randloc():
    return Vector((randint(0, 9) / 100 for i in range(3)))
 
for i in range(5):
    copy = ob.copy()
    me = copy.data = copy.data.copy()
    ds = randloc() # locally moved by random
    T = Matrix.Translation(-ds)
    # transform the origin
    me.transform(T)
    # move back globally
    copy.matrix_world.translation = mw @ ds
    # link to collection
    context.collection.objects.link(copy)
```

When run with Cube as context object, the result is cube and its 5 copies all occupying same bounding box, however there origins and locations are moved

```
>>> cubes = [o for o in C.scene.objects if o.name.startswith("Cube")]
>>> for cube in cubes:
...     cube.name, cube.location
...     
('Cube', Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)))
('Cube.001', Vector((0.029999999329447746, 0.03999999910593033, 0.05000000074505806)))
('Cube.002', Vector((0.03999999910593033, 0.05000000074505806, 0.0)))
('Cube.003', Vector((0.009999999776482582, 0.07999999821186066, 0.03999999910593033)))
('Cube.004', Vector((0.07000000029802322, 0.09000000357627869, 0.05000000074505806)))
('Cube.005', Vector((0.009999999776482582, 0.07999999821186066, 0.09000000357627869)))
```

Note in question code you are setting the global location of the scene cursor randomly, to use a random global instead within the range and method above convert the global random location

```
global_rand_loc = randloc()
ds = mw.inverted() @ global_rand_loc # local shift
... (as above)

copy.matrix_world.translation = global_rand_loc
```